# How to divide two longs and get the value?

Tags: java

I need to compute probability of an integer and a long. but I always get 0.

int a = 234;
long b = 123453344L

float c = a /b;

How to get it right in Java?

Answer (score 6):

You need to either cast one of them as a `float`, or declare one of the variables to be a `float` from the start.  Otherwise, Java's integer division takes over, and just as an `int` divided by an `int` must be an `int`, that would apply to `long`s as well.

```
float c = (float) a / b;
```

Answer (score 4):

you're using integer math, then storing the result in a float.

```
float c = ((float)a) / b;
```

would get you a float, but using doubles would be more precise.

or using BigDecimal

```
BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal(a).Divide(new BigDecimal(b));
```

Answer (score 2):

The division is done between not decimal values (integer and float), then the result will be not decimal then it is casted to float, but the decimal information is already lost.

you can either use decimal types (float, double, BigDecimal) in the entire operation or cast the values before they are used.

```
  float a = 234;
  float b = 123453344L;
  float c =  a/b;
```

or

```
  int a = 234;
  long b = 123453344L;
  float c = (float) a/b;
```

I hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

This is another approach to accomplish this:

```java
float c = a.floatValue() / b.floatValue();
```